# Merge lists and add listname in a new column

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, joined-view

As the title says I want to merge some lists with the same columns together and then add a new column with the name of the list this item was extracted from.
Is it possible to do this out of the box (with SharePoint online)?
If it's not possible I'd create a new empty merged list and a workflow for the content lists, which just writes changes in the merged list.
Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
List1:
item1
item2

List2:
item3
item4

MergedList:
item1 List1
item2 List1
item3 List2
item4 List2
```

Comment: why do you want to do this ? If they have the same columns, you can create a single list with a Choice field which tells the Category of the Item... just a thought!

Comment: The lists are project tasklists from different departments. This lists are synchronised with outlook, which doesn't allow custom columns.